# Http Requests Timing Out in Production but not Dev

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7

Below is an example of a website that when requested from my local dev environment returns ok but when requested from the production server, the request times out after 15 seconds. The request headers are exactly the same. Any ideas?

http://www.dealsdirect.com.au/p/wall-mounted-fish-tank-30cm/

Comment: Does the production server talk to a different back end? (e.g. different database or some such).

Comment: Without real informations only guess some can do. Start with the check that you are not running it on debug mode. Second check your Event viewer for the error.

Comment: I appreciate your help but I am not sure I understand your question and how it relates to my question. The dev server talks to my dev database and my production server to talks to the production database. But a database has nothing to do with this question, right? This is a communication issue between two servers. I should add this website is a different server than our server.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6028051/webrequest-create-the-operation-has-timed-out this is the same issue I agree, it is a vague question, but wondering if someone had the same issue

Answer (score 1):

Here's one thing that I wanna point beside what other stuff I've already provided. When you call `GetResponse` the object that's returned has to be disposed of ASAP. Otherwise stalling will occur, or rather the next call will block and possibly time out because there's a limit to the number of requests that can go through the HTTP request engine concurrently in `System.Net.`

```
// The request doesn't matter, it's not holding on to any critical resources
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

// The response however is, these will eventually be reclaimed by the GC
// but you'll run into problems similar to deadlocks if you don't dispose them yourself
// when you have many of them
using (var response = request.GetResponse())
{
    // Do stuff with `response` here
}
```

## This is my old answer

This question is really hard to answer without knowing more about the specifics. There's no reason why the IIS would behave like this which leads me to conclude that the problem has to do with something you app is doing but I know nothing about it. If you can reproduce the problem with a debugger attached you might be able to track down where the problem is occuring but if you cannot do this first then there's little I can do to help.

Are you using the ASP.NET Development Server or IIS Express in development?

If this is an issue with proxies here's a factory method I use to setup HTTP requests that require where the proxy requires some authentication (though, I don't believe I ever received a time out):

```
HttpWebRequest CreateRequest(Uri url)
{
    var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    request.Timeout = 120 * 1000;
    request.CookieContainer = _cookieContainer;
    if (UseSystemWebProxy)
    {
        var proxy = WebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy();
        if (UseDefaultCredentials)
        {
            proxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        }
        if (UseNetworkCredentials != null
            && UseNetworkCredentials.Length > 0)
        {
            var networkCredential = new NetworkCredential();
            networkCredential.UserName = UseNetworkCredentials[0];
            if (UseNetworkCredentials.Length > 1)
            {
                networkCredential.Password = UseNetworkCredentials[1];
            }
            if (UseNetworkCredentials.Length > 2)
            {
                networkCredential.Domain = UseNetworkCredentials[2];
            }
            proxy.Credentials = networkCredential;
        }
        request.Proxy = proxy;
    }
    return request;
}
```

Try this out Adrian and let me know how it goes.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6028051/webrequest-create-the-operation-has-timed-out this is the same issue I agree, it is a vague question, but wondering if someone had the same issue. Using IIS in develoment

Comment: One thing immediately comes to mind, you might be having issues with a proxy server acting up? What it says is that it cannot eastablish a connection because it timed out (that will happen if the connection is blocked) which could have happened for security reasons or proxy reasons. I have a snippet you might wanna try out, I'm gonna go digging for it.

Comment: We have had issues from time to time with making connections to remote servers but everything worked fine on dev and out continuous integration environment. but this request fails in prod and ci.

Comment: A developer environment is generally less restricive, it could be a access permission/code level security thing. It could be a lot of things to say the very least. How does the code look that is performing the request? Are there any differences between these environments?

Comment: I justed rememberd another thing, you are disposing the response right after you've finished with it, right? Because if you don't it will linger and you can only have 10 or so outstanding requests simultaneously. This problem might be more subtle on a developer machine but please check this. You should wrap your `GetResponse` call with a `using` statment or `try-finally` to clean up the resource as soon as your done with it.

Comment: cool, I am trying it out. is var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse(); still the way i want to make the call

Comment: Wrap that in a using statement: `using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse()){ /*...*/ }`

Comment: thanks I appreciate your help on this completely vague question. I think I am going to give our server managers a call and see if they can figure it out. We have no problems with 99% of the links we get on our site. I wonder why this one is an issue.

Comment: Well, this issue is obviously subtle a better understanding of is going will help but it can be really difficult to get at the details of such a problem without proper tools or experience.

Comment: Can you nest using statements? For the case where you need to get one response to make another?

Comment: Yeah sure, a `using` statment is just a short hand notation for a `try-finally` block with a call to Dispose, if the instance isn't null. But don't pass the same instance to multiple `using` statements. It will compile and it won't crash but it could cause undesirable effects when the object is being disposed before you inteded it to be.